# How can I filter out lines in a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code that shows the name of all .dll files within a directory on a rich textbox. How would I be able to filter/hide all filenames which I specify as unimportant and keep the rest?

Example:

Actual directory contains: 1.dll, 2.dll, 3.dll

Rich Textbox shows: 1.dll, 3.dll because 2.dll is specified as unimportant in the code.

Code I currently have that displays all files.

```
DirectoryInfo r = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V");
FileInfo[] rFiles = r.GetFiles("*.dll");
string rstr = "";
foreach (FileInfo rfile in rFiles)
{
    rstr = rstr + rfile.Name + "                                                                                                              ";
}
string strfinalR;
strfinalR = richTextBox3.Text + rstr;
richTextBox3.Text = (strfinalR);
```

Comment: Add ignorable DLLs to a HashSet<string> then test with .Contains() in the loop, ignoring if its true.

Comment: `r.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(file => !new string[] { "2", "8" }.Any( type => file.Name.Contains(type)));` where `new string[] { "2", "8" }` can be declared earlier as a member field/property.

Comment: Why not just use a simple `if` statement in your `foreach` loop?

Comment: I posted the code base of a RichTextBox which can be filtered here: [RichFilterableTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188933/richtextbox-with-text-filtering/60445431#60445431) maybe you can use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a blacklist :

```
string[] blacklist = new string[] { "2", "1337" };
```

and filter the filenames within your `foreach`

```
foreach(FileInfo rFile in rFiles)
{
    if(blacklist.Any(bl => rFile.Name.Contains(bl)))
        continue;
    // your code
}
```

or when you retrieve files from `r`

```
r.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(file => !blacklist.Any( type => file.Name.Contains(type))).ToArray();
```

Comment: When I try that I get: System.io.fileinfo does not contain a definition for contain.

Comment: I also tried implementing it into r.GetFiles but I then got: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerables' to 'System.IO.FIleInfo[]' An explicit conversion exists.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to make a list of files to ignore and then fetch all files excluding those in ignore list. Something like this:

```
//ignore list
List<string> filesToIgnore = new List<string>() { "2.dll", "some_other.dll" };

//get files and filter them            
DirectoryInfo r = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V");

List<FileInfo> rFiles = r.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(x => !filesToIgnore.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

//your existing code follows
string rstr = "";
foreach (FileInfo rfile in rFiles)
{
    rstr = rstr + rfile.Name + "                                                                                                              ";
}
string strfinalR;
strfinalR = richTextBox3.Text + rstr;
richTextBox3.Text = (strfinalR);
```